# problem of ploting trend and hatches where trend is not significant

Tags: python, plot, python-xarray, contourf

I am trying to plot trend of snow cover parameter and hatches where trend is not significant from an xarray dataset object. I use the following commands, but the map show only hatches and not trend values colors. The second problem is that i can not customize hatches size and color. Need your help, i am begginer in python.

Here is my code:

```
# Extract xarray datset of trend and pvalue
data=data_dic['ESA_GF']['scf_monthly_value'].loc[{'month':1}] 
data = data.where(data['scf_monthly_value']>1)
slope = data.scf_monthly_value_slope
slope=slope*10
pvalue = data.scf_monthly_value_p
pvalue = pvalue.where(pvalue > 0.05)


# Plot 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,
                        subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()}) #   figsize=(11,8.5)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.17,hspace=0.2)
set_size(14,7)       

slope.transpose().plot(ax=ax, cmap=cmap_init)
ax.contourf(pvalue.transpose(), hatches=['////'], alpha=0, colors=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the color of hatches you can either do `plt.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'color'` before assigning the hatch or `edgecolor='color'` when you plot whatever you want. example:
`plt.bar(0,2 hatch='/' , edgecolor = 'blue')`
To change the size you can do `plt.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = width`
example:

```
plt.rcParams['hatch.linewidth'] = 6
plt.bar(0,2,hatch='/' , edgecolor = 'blue')
```

I don't have an answear for your first question. Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jerry, I tried to follow what you have indicated but the problem persist.

Comment: @CHAABANI Hamid I updated the answer and now it should be more useful

Comment: That answers my second question, perfect,